# Is Kayaba's Admin Account a part of The Seed Nexus?

Tags: sword-art-online

At the end of the second Arc of the first season, Kirito was able to access Kayaba's Administrator Account and gained control of ALO's systems. Afterwards, Kayaba appeared and gave Kirito [*The Seed*](http://swordartonline.wikia.com/wiki/World_Seed), a free kernel of the Cardinal System for the creation of new games and allowing players to pass stats between games. This ended up creating The Seed Nexus.

Now I am wondering, since ALO and the Recreated SAO are a part of The Seed Nexus, can Kayaba's Administrator Account go between games?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it won't. The reason Kayaba's admin account works in ALO is that ALO uses the database of SAO. ALO is actually SAO with improvements here and there, changing the textures, adding flight system, etc. That's why Asuna is there. That's why when Kirito logged into ALO, he retrieved his stats and items, though, due to the change in game resources, his items are mostly broken.

So, it is reasonable to say that a game created from the Seed would not have Kayaba's admin account, since it doesn't have the same database. There is a chance that Kayaba would hard code his account into the Seed's program, but I don't think it is likely since hard-coding is a bad practice.

- StackOverflow: [What is your attitude towards hard coding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/828207/what-is-your-attitude-towards-hard-coding)

Comment: +1 for the bad practice thing. Additionally, when adapting the game, the hard-coded admin account would've probably been removed

Comment: @Vogel612 if they can find where he wrote that part, that is. Most of the time when using framework, people don't bother much with the existing framework codes and focus on creating new functions or overriding existing ones.